# Нужен ли вопросительный знак в предложениях типа: "Подскажите, пожалуйста..."?

Tags: пунктуация

Ставятся ли вопросительные знаки в предложениях типа: 
"Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли новости по даному вопросу()";
"Прошу сообщить, поступала ли дополнительная информация()".

В конце — точка или вопросительный знак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово "подскажите"  в тексте возможно при передаче устной речи, где оно вместо более "нормативного" слова "скажите" используется как *обращение* перед заданием *прямого вопроса* (подскажите = **ответьте на вопрос**). Перед самим вопросом в составе общего предложения нужно двоеточие:

> (Под)скажите, пожалуйста: есть (ли) новости по данному вопросу?
>
> (Под)скажите, пожалуйста! Есть (ли) новости по данному вопросу?

Для повествовательного предложения (напр. в официальном письме) нужно другое слово:

> Сообщите, пожалуйста, есть ли новости по данному вопросу.

Comment: Верно! Мне тоже режет слух, когда говорят "подскажите" вместо "скажите".

Answer (score 1):

Знак вопроса здесь неуместен, так как это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором главное (*Прошу сообщить*) — не вопросительное, а придаточное не содержит **прямого** вопроса.

[Розенталь. §76. Вопросительный знак](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/41.htm):

2. Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если придаточное предложение содержит в себе *прямой вопрос*, например: *Всякого рода нарушения, уклонения, отступления от правил приводили его в уныние, хотя, казалось бы, какое ему дело?* (Чехов).

**Примечание.** Если придаточное предложение образует косвенный вопрос, то в конце сложноподчиненного предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится, например: *Не знаю, сколько времени я пробыл в этом положении* (Л Толстой); *Ты не сказала нам, почему не ходишь в училище* (Федин). Постановка вопросительного знака после предложения с косвенным вопросом встречается, если последний содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, например: *Не понимаю, что тебе нужно*? (Чехов); *Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником?* (Горький).

Answer (score 0):

Вопросительный знак нужен, иначе это будет не вопросительное предложение, а повествовательное.