# Нужно ли ставить знак вопроса?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения, вопрос

Просьба уточнить нужно ли ставить знак вопроса в следующих предложениях:

1. Пожалуйста, объясните ещё раз подробнее, для совершения какой операции вы ожидаете кода на почте.
2. Анна, пожалуйста, уточните, вы пытаетесь войти в аккаунт (восстановить пароль) или создать новый аккаунт.

Вроде во втором случае знак вопроса ставится, а в первлм нет. Однако не могу найти этого правила :(

Comment: Во втором после "уточните", имхо, нужно двоеточие. И тогда нужен вопросительный знак.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435722/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0

Answer (score 1):

Предложение 1 - сложноподчинённое с придаточным изъяснительным, присоединяемым союзным словом - относительным местоимением КАКОЙ. В этом случае вопросительная интонация отсутствует, запятую не ставим.

***Пожалуйста, объясните ещё раз подробнее, для совершения какой операции вы ожидаете кода на почте.***

Предложение 2 - бессоюзное, вторая часть представляет собой вопросительное предложение, потому нужен знак вопроса. Но! После первой части требуется ДВОЕТОЧИЕ:

***Анна, пожалуйста,  уточните: вы пытаетесь войти в аккаунт (восстановить пароль) или создать новый аккаунт?***

**Перед прямым вопросом, включенным в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения, ставится двоеточие: *Спрашивается теперь: что же делало наше общество в последние 20 — 30 лет?*** (Добр.); Одного только я не понимаю: как она могла тебя укусить? (Ч.); До сих пор удивительным и неразгаданным остаётся: кто же в эту роковую ночь дивизионную школу снял с караула?’(Фурм.); Я прошёл к калитке по мокрой траве, испытывая тревогу: кто же рассмотрит первый трактор в таком непроглядном тумане? (Перв.) Ср.: Может быть, природа подсказывает нам: пользуйтесь красотой, принимайте её (Гран.) — своеобразный эквивалент прямой речи. [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы в обоих случаях рассматривала эти предложения как БСП (ставится двоеточие и знак вопроса).

***Пожалуйста, объясните ещё раз подробнее (следующее): для совершения какой операции вы ожидаете кода на почте?***

***Анна, пожалуйста, уточните: вы пытаетесь войти в аккаунт (восстановить пароль) или создать новый аккаунт?***

**Пояснение**

Если считать предложение (1) БСП, то местоимение ***какой*** будет вопросительным (а не союзным) словом.

Предложение (1) можно рассматривать как СПП с союзным словом ***какой*** (ставится запятая, нет вопросительного знака), но в таком виде оно не слишком удобно для прочтения ввиду распространенности. Сравнить: ***Объясните, для какОй операции вам нужен код.***